# ZEND Framework with Flickr

Tags: php, zend-framework, flickr

I'm referencing this page http://zendframework.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.service.flickr.html
In order to pull all albums off a flickr page.

But it only lists 6 'methods'
tagSearch()
userSearch()
getIdByUsername()
getIdByEmail()
groupPoolGetPhotos()
getImageDetails()

Where do I get a list of all the methods?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the FLickr.php source file in ./library/Zend/Service - it seems these are the only supported methods.

An alternative is to to check [Zend_Service_Flickr+2.0](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Service_Flickr+2.0+-+Mickael+Perraud) out

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in [the API of ZF](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/):

Select **Zend_Service** in the select, then [**Flickr > Classes**](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Service/Flickr/Zend_Service_Flickr.html) in the left tree menu.